# How to make rows touch in Microsoft Access reports table?

Tags: ms-access, report

When I generate a table using the reports feature in Access, there seems to be a small space between each row in the table. I don't want this space would like to know if there's a way to make the rows touch.

The space is very small but I would like there to be no space at all:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the below changes are to be done in `Design view`.

- make sure that all controls of the section have the same `Height`,
- then set their `Top`/`Bottom` `Padding` and `Margin` properties to 0
- then their `Top` to 0, meaning they are at the very top of their section.  You won't be able to set the top to 0 if the Padding/Margins are no 0.

Then make sure the `Section(?).Height` property is the same as the controls `Height`.

That should do it.

Eventually check the border of the controls (`Hairline` size).

Most of these operations can be done at once by clicking in the left margin of the report to select all the controls on that line, and changing in the Property Sheet, so it's quick do.

Comment: Where can I find the Section(?).Height property?

Comment: in the Property Sheet

Comment: In the property sheet I only see an option to change the Height. The height is the same for every column and Top = 0. What else should be changed?

Comment: The section Height, as indicated. Clcik the section and check the Height

Comment: The section height is the same as the controls height but there is still a space between the rows. Is there anything else that needs to be done?